# Evaluating $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{n-i}{n \choose i}f(i)$

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, power-series

From Enumerative Combinatorics by Stanley:

> Evaluate $$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{n-i}{n \choose i}f(i)$$
>   where $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{f(n)x^{n}}{(n)!}=\exp\bigg(x+\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg)$$

I tried splitting up the summation using the Cauchy product into:$$\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n!f(i)}{i!}\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\bigg)$$
which I think is correct however I'm not quite sure where to go from here. I asked my professor the problem but he didn't have time to really go over the answer with me and mentioned it may have to do with the Möbius inversion and that I should come back to this question after studying that.

However, it doesn't make sense then for the book to ask me the question in chapter 1 so the author must have a different method in mind. A couple examples before this we did derive that:
$$e^x=\prod_{n\ge1}(1-x^n)^{-\mu(n)/n}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function of number theory which I only mention because of my professor's comment. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the second expression after "where": Are you sure you have that factor $\large n!$ in the denominator ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: For the Cauchy product you should have

$$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}f(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\frac{f(k)}{k!}(-1)^{n-k}\;.$$

The lefthand side is

$$\exp\left(x+\frac{x^2}2\right)\cdot e^{-x}=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)\;.$$

Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Is it  $\sum_{n\ge0,2|n}\frac{1}{2^nn!}$? Also, the only thing I don't understand is where the $n!$ from the n in $\binom{n}i$ goes/cancels as is evident by the $n!$ in my incorrect expansion.

Comment: @Eric: $\exp\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{n!}\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!2^n}$, so the coefficients of the odd powers are $0$, and the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ is $\frac1{n!2^n}$. Finally, the coefficient of $\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ is $\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}=(2n-1)!!$.

Comment: @Eric: The missing $n!$ is a typo on my part, which I’ve now fixed.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I can already tell studying out of this book is going to be quite the undertaking, but I will take it as far as my patience allows me.

Comment: @Eric: You’re welcome (and sorry about the typo). One good thing: MSE has quite a few people who are likely to be able to help with this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Notice

$$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n\choose k}f(k)=\sum_{a+b=n}\frac{f(a)}{a!}\frac{(-1)^{b}}{b!}.$$

Thus, $1/n!$ times the expression you want is the $x^n$ coefficient of the product of the exponential generating functions of $f(\cdot)$ and $(-1)^\bullet$. So look at the coefficients of $\exp(-x)\exp\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$.